# Display local JSON file data in a chart in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, bar-chart

I'm working with JSON manipulation in ASP.NET MVC for the first time, therefore facing few problems. What I want to do is:

1) Read all the data from local JSON file using C# MVC, and
2) Then display the required fetched data using any chart / graph.

Controller Code:

```
    public class MoviesController : Controller
        {
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Genres.json")))
            {
                var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Genres>>(sr.ReadToEnd());

            return View(jsonResult);

        }
    }

    public ActionResult Movies()
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Movies.json")))
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movies>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            return View(json);
        }
    }
```

Genres.cs :

```
public class Genres
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Movies.cs :

```
public class Movies
    {
        public string Overview { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public Array GenreIDs { get; set; }
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public string OriginalTitle { get; set; }
        public string OriginalLanguage { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Genres.json:

```
[{
                "id": 28,
                "name": "Action"
            }, {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Adventure"
            }, {
                "id": 16,
                "name": "Animation"
            }, {
                "id": 35,
                "name": "Comedy"
            }, {
                "id": 27,
                "name": "Horror"
            }, {
                "id": 10402,
                "name": "Music"
            }, {
                "id": 9648,
                "name": "Mystery"
            }, {
                "id": 10749,
                "name": "Romance"
            }
        ]
```

Movies.json: 
[{

```
            "overview": "Raj is a rich, carefree, happy-go-lucky second generation NRI. Simran is the daughter of Chaudhary Baldev Singh, who in spite of being an NRI is very strict about adherence to Indian values. Simran has left for India to be married to her childhood fiancé. Raj leaves for India with a mission at his hands, to claim his lady love under the noses of her whole family. Thus begins a saga.",
            "release_date": "1995-10-20",
            "genre_ids": [35, 18, 10749],
            "id": 19404,
            "original_title": "Dilwale Dulhania Le Jayenge",
            "original_language": "hi",
            "title": "Dilwale Dulhania Le Jayenge",
        }, {
            "overview": "Framed in the 1940s for the double murder of his wife and her lover, upstanding banker Andy Dufresne begins a new life at the Shawshank prison, where he puts his accounting skills to work for an amoral warden. During his long stretch in prison, Dufresne comes to be admired by the other inmates -- including an older prisoner named Red -- for his integrity and unquenchable sense of hope.",
            "release_date": "1994-09-23",
            "genre_ids": [18, 80],
            "id": 278,
            "original_title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
            "original_language": "en",
            "title": "The Shawshank Redemption",
        }, {
            "overview": "The true story of how businessman Oskar Schindler saved over a thousand Jewish lives from the Nazis while they worked as slaves in his factory during World War II.",
            "release_date": "1993-11-29",
            "genre_ids": [18, 36, 10752],
            "id": 424,
            "original_title": "Schindler's List",
            "original_language": "en",
            "title": "Schindler's List",
        }
]
```

This is the updated code in which I have successfully read the JSON files of Genre and Movies. Now what I want to do is to show the data of these JSON files in the form of charts (pie, bar etc) and then apply some filters as well. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of the chart libraries has pretty good documentation.Did you try any ?

Comment: Didn't go that far up till now. Just got the JSON file read successfully. Now, I'll see how to display that data using charts.

Comment: Yes, I did try AmCharts but it doesn't seems to load my json file.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a video on you tube about how to use Highcharts with asp.net mvc. you can find it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRwID9v5iKA&t=1s

Updated Answer:

```
 public ActionResult YourActionName()
    {
        //I dont know whether you load data from database or other resource 
        //But lets see your data as form of two lists
        var movies=new List<Movie>()
        {
            new Movie() { Overview="Raj is a rich,....." // other properties }
            //other movies here
        };

        var genres = new List<Genre>()
        {
            new Genre() { Name="Action"// other properties } }
            //other movies here
        };


        return Json(new {Movies= movies, Genres= genres });
    }
```

Sample:

Please take a look at [this sample](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1f3f2a/charting-in-mvc/)

Comment: Your video is really helping but can you guide me on how can I use my data which is a JSON object having two field (Genres and Movies) in form of pie chart? Thanks in advance. I have accessed Genres and Movies separately but unable to do so combined and show them in chart-form.

Comment: I'll using data from a local JSON file which I've mentioned in my question. I'm able to read the JSON files separately like this:                                             public ActionResult Index()
       {

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Genres.json")))
            {
                var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Genres>>(sr.ReadToEnd());

                return View(jsonResult);

            }
        }

Comment: public ActionResult Movies()
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Movies.json")))
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movies>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
                return View(json);
            }
        }

Comment: would you please update your answer to reflect what you have mentioned in comments?

Comment: I've updated my question now by updating the code. Requirement: I want to do is to show the data of these JSON files in the form of charts (pie, bar etc) and then apply some filters as well. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code does not return json, it returns view. please consider my example again, also you need to call the action through ajax, have you tried it ?

Comment: My code does return JSON data which I'm able to display using View. All I need to do is to show that data using chart / graph which I'm showing as a List right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third-party Charts like AMCharts https://www.amcharts.com/demos/exporting-chart-to-image/ or Google Charts

Comment: It didn't work :(                                                                         
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="amcharts/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "dataLoader": {
                "url": "~/App_Data/Genres.json",
                "format": "json"
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
</body>
</html>'

Comment: have you import js file ?